# SGX and TPM interface

Tags: tpm, sgx

I was looking through the documentation of SGX and could not find any description of how to access the contents of a TPM. According to their claims that should although be possible!?
Has anyone experience in this?

Comment: Where do they claim that this is possible?

Comment: I also think that SGX is a TEE (trusted execution environment), not a TPM (trusted platform module) which is a separate chip on the motherboard. If you have the possibility to access it via the OS, you can of course use the untrusted part of the application to communicate with the TPM.